# When i select the combobox1 last value the combobox2 last value will be automatically selected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 **Combo-boxes** I want to achieve something like this,
When i select the **combobox1** last **value** the **combobox2** last **value** will be automatically selected,How can i achieve this using C# Code,
please help me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bellow Code Work Fine For Me anyway thanks to all for your replays... :)

```
  private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (combobox1.SelectedIndex == (combobox1.Items.Count - 1))
        {
            combobox2.SelectedIndex = combobox2.Items.Count - 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `SelectionChanged` event of `ComboBox1`, set the `SelectedIndex` of `ComboBox2` to **(the number of items in `ComboBox2`) - 1)**. This code should work:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = ComboBox2.Items.Count - 1
End Sub
```